# AndroidX Media3 migration guide

Tags: android, media-player, android-media3

I'm currently in the process of migrating from ExoPlayer (com.google.android.exoplayer2 version 2.19.1) to Media3 (1.1.1) in my Android app. I've followed the migration instructions provided in the
[official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/migration-guide).

I've made the necessary code and dependency changes, but I'm encountering an error when inflating the androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView in my XML layout. Specifically, I'm getting the following error:

```java
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in 
com.xxx.xx:layout/mpeg_player: Binary XML file line #16 in 
com.xxxx.xx:layout/mpeg_player: Error inflating class 
androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
```

and further

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML 
file line #78 in com.xxx.xx:layout/exo_player_control_view: 
Binary XML file line #78 in com.xxx.xx:layout/exo_player_control_view: 
Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
                                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78 in com.xxx.xxx:layout/exo_player_control_view: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
```

here is my xml

```
<androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        app:show_buffering="always"
        app:show_subtitle_button="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:use_controller="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and added all dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.1.1'
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-session:1.1.1"
```

also added this to my build.gradle

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully migrate to Media3. Thank you!

Comment: Just for stating out the obvious, did you synchronize gradle after changing the dependencies?

Comment: yes I synchronized gradle after changing the dependencies

Comment: Just saw `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar`. this is still exoplayer2. So you most likely removed `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.X.X'` or?

Comment: @Vall0n I was using that before and just migrated.  my imports

Comment: import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem;
import androidx.media3.common.Player;
import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi;
import androidx.media3.common.util.Util;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView;  @Vall0n my imports

Comment: Can you try to just add `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.19.1` in the dependency section of the `app.gradle` file. Then synchronize and try to build again. 
Also can you post the layout `com.ifma.cinema:layout/exo_player_control_view`?

Comment: @Vall0n you are awesome, I had  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>  exo_player_control_view and made the change and everything was solved

Comment: Thank you! :)
I will post my Comment as answer and then you can give the answer and thumbs up and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you still using `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar` in one of your layouts.

So, can you try to update the `DefaultTimeBar` to `androidx.media3.ui.DefaultTimeBar` in your layout.